# Can't implicitly connect port on instance error

Tags: system-verilog

I'm new to systemverilog and I'm having this error that I can't seem to figure out. This is the error message:

> Error (10897): SystemVerilog error at TopLevel.sv(103): can't
>   implicitly connect port "ALU_SRC_B" on instance "control_module" of
>   module "Control" - no such object is visible in the present scope

This is the piece of code that's failing:

```
// Control module
Control control_module (
    .Instruction(Instruction[8:5]),
     .ALU_OP,
     .ALU_SRC_B,
     .REG_WRITE,
     .BRANCH,
     .MEM_WRITE,
     .MEM_READ,
     .REG_DST,
     .MEM_TO_REG,
    .HALT(HALT)
);
```

And this is my Control Module:

```
module Control(
    input        [8:0] Instruction,
    output logic [3:0] ALU_OP,
    output logic [1:0] ALU_SRC_B,
    output logic       REG_WRITE,
    output logic       BRANCH,
    output logic       MEM_WRITE,
    output logic       MEM_READ,
    output logic       REG_DST,
    output logic       MEM_TO_REG,
    output logic       HALT
    );

     logic [3:0] OPCODE = Instruction[8:5];
    always_comb begin
...
```

The Control Module is in the correct directory so why am I getting this error?

Comment: Where you instance `Control control_module (` do you have a wire called `ALU_SRC_B`? We need to see the wire as well as the instance.

Comment: Please paste all your tb code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gave your code a try and the reason you get the message is that for your unconnected ports in **control_module**, you need to show empty brackets to indicate this is unconnected. Otherwise, you get the message as shown (which is a little cryptic).

TESTBENCH:

```
module tb;

  wire[8:0] Instruction;
  wire      HALT;
// Control module
Control control_module (
    .Instruction(Instruction[8:5]),
  .ALU_OP(),
  .ALU_SRC_B(),
  .REG_WRITE(),
  .BRANCH(),
  .MEM_WRITE(),
  .MEM_READ(),
  .REG_DST(),
  .MEM_TO_REG(),
    .HALT(HALT)
);

  initial begin
    #100ns
    $finish;
  end

endmodule
```

DESIGN:

```
// Code your design here
module Control(
    input        [8:0] Instruction,
    output logic [3:0] ALU_OP,
    output logic [1:0] ALU_SRC_B,
    output logic       REG_WRITE,
    output logic       BRANCH,
    output logic       MEM_WRITE,
    output logic       MEM_READ,
    output logic       REG_DST,
    output logic       MEM_TO_REG,
    output logic       HALT
);

endmodule
```

You can find a working example here: https://www.edaplayground.com/x/63Eq

Try taking out one of the empty brackets and notice you get the same error message..